# Can Nginx insert a missing "/" or missing "/bla/" in a URL?

Tags: nginx

Looking through the error.log file of Nginx, we can see requests coming as one of two incorrect patterns:

- http://www.example.com/app-contextmoduleA/controller1 -> should be http://www.example.com/app-context/moduleA/controller1
- http://www.example.com/app-contextcontroller2 -> should be http://www.example.com/app-context/moduleB/controller2

The current Nginx configuration looks like this:

```
server {

  listen        8080;

  location /app-context/ {

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/app-context/;
  }
}
```

The challenge is inserting the missing / after app-context (for the first wrong URL) or missing /moduleB/ (for the second wrong URL). It doesn't look like try_files would support that, and I have not found a way to do it with rewrite.

Is there a way for Nginx to rewrite the URLs for both use cases? In particular, I would prefer not to have to know all the name of the modules or controllers in advance. There are many, so "hard-coding" them in the rewrite rule would be onerous.

Comment: for instance, `rewrite ^(/app-context)([^/].+)$ $1/$2 last;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through quite a few online resources and through trial and error, I was able to come to a good-enough solution:

```
location /app-context {   
    location ~ (moduleA|moduleB) {
      # inserts a forward slash after app-context if not there, 
      # e.g. /app-contextmoduleA/foo/bar to /app-context/moduleA/foo/bar
      rewrite ^(/app-context(?!/))(.*) $1/$2 break;
      try_files $uri @proxy;
    }
    # inserts /defaultModule/ after app-context
    # e.g. /app-context/controller1 to /app-context/defaultModule/controller1
    rewrite ^(/app-context(?!/defaultModule/))(.*) $1/defaultModule/$2 break;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These should handle your example case:

```
    location /app-context {
        rewrite ^(/app-contextmoduleA)/(.*)$ /app-context/moduleA/$2 permanent;
        rewrite ^(/app-contextcontroller2) /app-context/moduleB/controller2 permanent;
        ...
    }
```

Check the ngx_http_rewrite_module for more info.

Comment: There are many modules and controllers, so I would need to replace moduleA and controller2 by "any characters."

For example, with `\/app-context(?!\/moduleA)(.*)` I can find the patterns that need to be fixed.